# How can I execute a Stored Procedure with DateTime SQL Server values in LINQPad?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures, linqpad, date-formatting

I want to see what values a Stored Procedure returns in LINQPad. It takes four args, two strings followed by two DateTimes.

I tried this:

```
sp_Platypus("Gramps", "WilfredOwen", "2015-09-01 15:16:16.622", "2015-09-30 15:16:16.622");
```

...but it fails with, "*cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.DateTime?'*"

This works, but (reasonably) gives me no results:

```
sp_Platypus("Gramps", "WilfredOwen", DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now);
```

So I tried to do it with date math this way:

```
sp_Platypus("Gramps", "WilfredOwen", DateTime.Now-120, DateTime.Now-30);
```

...but that is rejected because it thinks the last args are not Date vals but int vals

I also tried this (just the date, no time element):

```
sp_Platypus("Gramps", "WilfredOwen", "2015-09-01", "2015-09-30");
```

...to no avail, and probably a few other things.

### UPDATE

Thanks to JamieD77: If I do this:

```
sp_Platypus("Gramps", "WilfredOwen", DateTime.Now.AddDays(-120), DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30));
```

...with "C# Statement(s)" selected from the Language dropdown, and my SQL Server connection selected from the Connection dropdown, it is accepted as valid.

Comment: try passing datetime in iso format yyyymmdd

Comment: if `DateTime.Now` is not throwing an error, can't you just use `DateTime.Now.AddDays(-120)`  and `DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30)`?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, too. With this:
cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.DateTime?'
I get, "cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.DateTime?'

Comment: `Convert.ToDateTime("2015-09-01 15:16:16.622")` will also give you a System.DateTime

Comment: The "Yeah, I tried that" was to Harsh before there was another comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This (using YYYYMMDD format) works:

```
Select * FROM PlatypusDetail WHERE MemberName = 'Duckbill Bill' AND PoisonToeDate > '20150601' AND PoisonToeDate < '20150630'
```